# How to set tcolorbox into fix location?

Tags: vertical-alignment, tcolorbox

We use `tcolorbox` for `algorithm` as shown in code, but the the location of algorithm isn't fix location or include with paragraph, so what should I do?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{talgo}[2][]{%
  blanker,float=tbp,grow to left by=#2,grow to right by=#2,
  before upper={\begin{algorithm}[H]},
  after upper={\end{algorithm}},
  #1
}


\begin{document}

text \ref{alg:euclid}

\begin{talgo}{1cm}
\caption{Euclid's algorithm}\label{alg:euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Euclid}{$m,l$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of m and l}
\State $r\gets m\bmod l$
\While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
\State $m\gets l$
\State $l\gets r$
\State $r\gets m\bmod l$
\EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
\State \textbf{return} $l$\Comment{The gcd is l}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{talgo}

\end{document}
```

the the result:
[image]

Comment: Remove  `float=tbp` in the definition of the `talgo` environment.

Comment: There's also the command `\tcolorboxenvironment` which transforms an existing environment into an `tcolorbox` - like one, however, this will not provide the 2nd argument which seems to be necessary.

Comment: @Bernard: How about writing up the answer?

Answer (score 2):

The `float=tbp` option in the definition of `talgo` takes precedence over the `[H]{ option of`algorithm`. You should remove it.

I took the opportunity to improve (in my opinion) the layout of comments, so they all begin at the same point, with the `eqparbox` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum} %
\usepackage{eqparbox}
 \usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{talgo}[2][]{%
  blanker, grow to left by=#2,grow to right by=#2,
  before upper={\begin{algorithm}[H]},
  after upper={\end{algorithm}},
  #1
}

\usepackage{cleveref} %

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
See \cref{alg:euclid}.
\begin{talgo}{1cm}
  \caption{Euclid's algorithm}\label{alg:euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$m,l$}\Comment{\eqmakebox[Com][l]{The g.c.d. of m and l}}
    \State $r\gets m\bmod l$
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{\eqmakebox[Com][l]{We have the answer if r is 0}}
    \State $m\gets l$
    \State $l\gets r$
    \State $r\gets m\bmod l$
    \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
    \State \textbf{return} $l$\Comment{\eqmakebox[Com][l]{The gcd is l}}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{talgo}

\end{document}
```

[image]